# iOS Universal Links on Older versions of iOS App

Tags: ios

I have two versions of my app, version 1 and version 2. In version 2 I added support for a new universal link `/sign-up`. I updated my app site association file to add `/sign-up` to the list of supported deep link URLs.

In version 1 I am returning `false` for `/sign-up` when I receive the `UIApplicationDelegate` callback for `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler`

In version 2, I am returning `true` for the same method and signing up the user.

The issue is that iOS is opening my app even for users on version 1, even though that version doesn't actually support this link.

How can I version universal links such that this sort of thing cannot happen in the future?

Comment: If the app versions have the same bundle id then any urls in your ASAA file are going to trigger the app, regardless of its version.  If a particular version can't handle the URL, it should call `open` on that URL to redirect back to safari.

Comment: @Paulw11 App versions have the same bundleID. Even if I add `open` as a fallback now, all previous versions are going to dead end as they won't have support for `open`. Based on Apples documentation they make it sound like falling back to `open` is what they do for you, but thats not my experience.

Comment: No, you have to call `open` yourself.  They don't do it for you unfortunately.  There is nothing you can do about the old apps that are out there.  You can only fix it for the future.

Comment: @hey Paulw11 do you have a link to the Apple Documentation where it says to open Safari please?